# How can set Page Moderation (block words) via Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]

I try using Graph API /{page-id}/settings

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/settings

It can read only, not updatable **PAGE_MODERATION_BLACKLIST** setting

Is there a way I can set this value by Graph API ?
If NOT, Where can I request facebook to allow this value set?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done via the Graph.  Facebook may add the functionality to alter a list of blocked words in time, but right now it is impossible.

Comment: Yes, I think no one use this function much, so it not listed in document yet.